# How to use OneLogin toolkit to post SAML responses with assertions to the service provider using X509 cert. in .net

Tags: c#, .net, saml, onelogin

I have an application where the users login with their usernames and passwords. Once they are on a particular page, they need to click a button to generate a report. That report is something the service provider provides and which is external to our application.

They need us to send a SAML response with saml assertions  exncrypted with the x509 cert. How can I implement that with the OneLogin? The toolkit only talks about cases where the SAML assertions are received, I need to post one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/saml-assertions/generate-saml-assertion

This will allow you (if you have an API key and a username & password) to generate a SAML assertion for the application.

Mind you, it's a far better model for the external application to just support SP-initiated SAML.

This way you'd simply direct them to the app, the app would get them to authenticate to OneLogin (or any other identity provider) and if the user signs in, it would direct them to the report.

I highly recommend you go the latter route.